# windows Installer - uninstalling previous version when the versions differ in installation policy (per-user, per-machine)

Tags: windows-installer

We have a visio plugin (say, version 1) which was installed by the User with Admin rights as per-user (‘Just me’ otpion) and the msi installer was created using setup and deployment of visual studio. Later because of organization policy in place to revoke admin privileges for all users were revoked. So the new version (version 2) needs to be installed by a IT admin as per-machine (everyone option) in order for the plugin to be available for all users on that machine and also to uninstall the old version (version 1) installed by the User whose permissions were revoked.

We are trying to automate the uninstallation to avoid manual intervention. The utility works by detecting all installed instances of the application by looking at registry keys on that machine and forcing uninstall with msiexec. But msiexec fails to uninstall the version that was installed by other user with exitcode as 1605 -  This action is only valid for the products that are currently installed

If the User (who installed the version 1 plugin) is given admin rights to uninstall the application, he is able to manually uninstall it that proves that the application not tampered and is in a state that can be uninstalled without any issues.

Any pointers about how to programmatically uninstall application installed on a machine that has been installed by the other user with ‘Just me’ option would really help

Comment: Sorry, out of luck. Visual Studio setup packages are notoriously bad, and per-user packages installed by administrators to per-machine locations are the worst of it. You're out of luck I'm sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just a Visual Studio problem.  Windows Installer doesn't allow the installation context (user/machine) to change durin an upgrade.  You have to perform logon as the user profile(s) that did the installation(s)  and remove them before installing the new per-machine install.

Comment: You are right. We reached out to Microsoft support and the answer was its by design. Only way is to manually do an uninstall and then do auto install.

Comment: @Christopher Painter     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450998/installscopedlg-in-custom-wix-ui-not-working help me solve this

Answer (score 3):

I found some further documentation:

*The following approach can be used to eliminate existing **per user** installs and install the new package **per machine*** if you are using **Installshield**. The same should be possible to do with your own replacement CA for "ISSetAllUsers" if you don't use Installshield. The following assumes a properly populated Upgrade table for a "major upgrade" - do a search for info on major upgrades:

1. Insert Installshield's **ISSetAllUsers** custom action before **FindRelatedProducts**. This action will read the value of ALLUSERS for the existing install, and enforce it for the new setup. See below for how to get this action added.
2. Move **RemoveExistingProducts** early in the sequence, before **InstallInitialize**.
3. Right after **RemoveExistingProducts** use a **set property CA** to set **ALLUSERS** back to 1.
4. *It is **very important** that both the above operations are done before **InstallInitialize***. If the value of **ALLUSERS** changes after **InstallInitialize** all components will be in an unrecognized state after installation and a self-repair will generally occur.

In order to insert the ISSetAllUsers custom action you need to do as follows:

1. In Installshield select Tools -> Options -> General -> Enable "Automatically create ISSetAllUsers action". Click OK.
2. Go to the upgrades view and insert a dummy entry.
3. Go to direct editor, remove the dummy entry from the Upgrade table.
4. The ISSetAllUsers action should have been inserted. Go to the InstallExecuteSequence view and move the action before FindRelatedProducts.

**Important:** Please note that the **ISSetAllUsers** custom action should never be added to any project unless you need to perform a per-user to per-machine migration. The action will effectively ensure that the new setup is installed with the same value as the old setup unless a set property custom action is used to force a per machine install (as we do in the scenario described above).

Comment: This will only remove the installation for the current user. All other users will then see both, the old and new version, in "Add or remove programs". Do you know of a way to do this for all users?

Answer (score 1):

I created a package to do this years ago, but for my life I can't find it ([see answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12291807/129130)). As I recall it involved using a **major upgrade** and the **Upgrade table** to uninstall the per user installation in the context of the right user, and then using a **set property custom action** to change the value of **ALLUSERS** before the new install hits **InstallInitialize** and performs a new install per-machine. This means that you must move **RemoveExistingProduct** as early in the **InstallExecuteSequence** as possible, and then do the set property right after it.

Sounds crazy, but as far as I recall it worked after some serious testing and debugging. The critical part is to run the new installer as the user who originally installed the per user install. This is not always easy to do logistically since sccm might run the install in a different context. It also might be that you have to move the RemoveExistingProducts even earlier in the sequence, and move some standard actions behind it to make it work. I don't recall exactly - sorry. You could use **[ActiveSetup](http://www.ewall.org/tech/msi/self-healing)** to schedule the install to run "once per user". You then might need to suppress the setup GUI to avoid bombing out with error messages to each and every user if the install isn't present.

Note that the above is difficult to do in Orca. Try in Wise for Windows Installer or Installshield. Note that Installshield packages also has their own way of reyanking the value of ALLUSERS, and you might need to disable their variant to make yours work. It isn't supposed to be easy :-).

Comment: Added a new answer, leaving this for reference too.

Comment: Thanks for your input. We are not using Installshield.