# Uninstall old version before installing new one

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I made major changes on my project and I create a new setup to update the old version. The new changes should be installed for all users but the old version wasn't like that (user has the right to choose if he want to install it for all user or only a specific user). I did the following things to make things work fine:
VS Setup:

1. InstallAllUsers = true
2. DetectNewerVersion = true
3. RemovePreviousVersion = true
4. Changed setup version
5. Regenerate new Product code
6. Rebuild the setup folder

After that, I tried to updated to the new version but what happened is it has overridden the old version and didn't delete all files that exists in different location also I found that I have two products now in control panel instead of one.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Is this a VS Setup project or a Wix toolset project ?

Comment: vs setup project

Comment: [There is an old answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12291807/129130) on this topic, but that is for Installshield. [WiX creator Rob Mensching explains the underlying MSI problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659159/129130).

Comment: it's not wix, I said this.