# InstallScopeDlg in Custom Wix UI not working

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

Hi i have developed an setup with wix and now i need to ask users wether its AllUser or perUser.After a long research i found that InstallScopeDLg can make it possible.But I have added custom UI with my wix and i wasn't able to add InstallScopeDlg with this custom UI in WIX.

```
    <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ReadmeDlg" Order="2">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="MyInstallScopeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="MyInstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ReadmeDlg" Order="2"></Publish>


      <Publish Dialog="ReadmeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ReadmeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="2"></Publish>
```

and this is my InstallScopeDlg code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI>
  <Dialog Id="MyInstallScopeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallScopeDlg_Title)" KeepModeless="yes">
    <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgBannerBitmap)" />
    <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="20" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgDescription)" />
    <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgTitle)" />
    <Control Id="BothScopes" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="20" Y="55" Width="330" Height="120" Property="WixAppFolder" Hidden="yes">
      <RadioButtonGroup Property="WixAppFolder">
        <RadioButton Value="WixPerUserFolder" X="0" Y="0" Width="295" Height="16" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgPerUser)" />
        <RadioButton Value="WixPerMachineFolder" X="0" Y="60" Width="295" Height="16" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgPerMachine)" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
      <Condition Action="show">Privileged AND (!(wix.WixUISupportPerUser) AND !(wix.WixUISupportPerMachine))</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="PerUserDescription" Type="Text" X="33" Y="70" Width="300" Height="36" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgPerUserDescription)">
      <Condition Action="show">!(wix.WixUISupportPerUser)</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="NoPerUserDescription" Type="Text" X="33" Y="70" Width="300" Height="36" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgNoPerUserDescription)">
      <Condition Action="show">NOT !(wix.WixUISupportPerUser)</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="PerMachineDescription" Type="Text" X="33" Y="131" Width="300" Height="36" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgPerMachineDescription)">
      <Condition Action="show">Privileged</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" />
    <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>
  </Dialog>
</UI>
```

and for RadioButtonGroup Property="WixAppFolder" in InstallScopeDlg

> i have added      in product.wxs file

and am getting the error code as

> Error    10  The Windows Installer XML variable
>   !(wix.WixUISupportPerUser) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   declared on the command line for light.exe, via a WixVariable element,
>   or inline using the syntax !(wix.WixUISupportPerUser=some value which
>   doesn't contain parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

Hence it we need to initially declare its components under the fragment section in your myinstallscopedlg.wxs

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>

    <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerUser" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerMachine" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />

          <UI>
                <Dialog Id="MyInstallScopeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallScopeDlg_Title)" KeepModeless="yes">
```

by doing this this ERROR **The Windows Installer XML variable !(wix.WixUISupportPerUser) is unknown.**  will be solved