# Why doesn't this installer install HKCR registries if I run it with systemcontext?

Tags: windows-installer, windows-7-x64, packaging, registrykey

I'm trying to install an application (Renishaw WiREMemFileViewer) in system context but it doesn't install it's registries to HKCR, it install them to HKU - DEFAULT.

With system context it doesn't even appear in Programs and Features but the registry key for it is on it's place and it is the same as the one the installer creates with a simple (Admin) install.

What can be the problem?

*This is an MSI installer and in the registry table I can't see these registry entries but if I give 0 condition to all the custam actions, it still won't install them to HKCR.*

Comment: When I tried to gave 0 as condition for the custom actions I added these registries to the registry table through component view so the package contained them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear if you have tried setting **ALLUSERS=1** on the msiexec command line? Try it if you haven't already.

[**ALLUSERS=1**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx) sets the install context to all users ("per-machine" instead of "per-user"). This affects among other things what hive (HKCU or HKLM) the setup writes certain registry keys to.

It is also possible that the application itself writes data on launch to HKCU. You can inspect the settings there, and manually add the file association keys to your MSI as per-machine data by writing them to HKCR.

---

Just a couple of links:

- [**MSDN, information about the ALLUSERS property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Uninstall with Product Code Fails "Installation Source Not Available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249747/uninstall-with-product-code-fails-installation-source-not-available/21409326#21409326)
- [install file under every user profile](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=15447)

Comment: I haven't tried it...  and adding ALLUSERS 1 property simply solved the problem that I tried to figure out all day. So thank you!